# setInterval performance impact between different intervals

Tags: javascript, performance, cpu, setinterval

It is well known that running `setInterval` with higher interval has better performance.

My question is How much better?

I have a timer in my web site that currently present the current time every 15 seconds using `setInterval`. I would like to change the interval to one second (1000 ms).

- How much it will affect my web site performance?
- Can it interfere with my UI?
- Is it something I even need to consider?

For the simplicity lets say that the function I sent to `setInterval` has only one line:

```
document.getElementById("time").innerText = Date.now();
```

Comment: No, this is not something you need to consider.

Comment: @vanneto any explantions? source? can it interfere with my UI?

Comment: As far as I know, it will not harm your UI itself. At the same time, it is possible that it will run something that may have an influence to UI (synchronous AJAX request, for instance). If you have nothing complicated with huge amount of DOM modifications inside, you should have no problem there.

Comment: And in any case, this is something to consider after everything is done. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Your question showcases this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

For intervals around 1+ second that do only little work you don't need to worry too much.

Only long-running callbacks interfere with the UI. Performance is affected when you're running code many times a second or your code is expensive (lots of calculations or big DOM modifications).

If you wanted to be really nice, you could use [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) to disable the interval when the page is inactive.